# Java vs. PHP Speed Comparison

Tags: java, php, performance

Which language is faster for web, Java or PHP?

Comment: Can't objectively answer this question, it is too open-ended.  What are you measuring the speed of?  It could just be argumentative.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359718/php-speed-vs-other-languages ?

Comment: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=java&lang2=php

Answer (score 45):

It is a difficult one to answer as in theory Java should be faster:
it's precompiled, any trivial algorithim will run faster in Java than PHP and there has been a vast amount of work done to optimise Java from improving the code, standard libraries, to JIT compilers, etc.

PHP is loaded and interpreted every time if you're not using the Zend optimiser, objects are intialised on every execution, even the most trivial string varaible is actually a complex object with many methods to support.

The problem is that in practice PHP sites seem to run faster using fewer resources.

I think this is because PHP developers take a more straightforward approach to design and don't get lost trying to implement exotic design patterns and implementing endless pointless abstractions.

Comment: The last paragraph is interesting.  Do you have any examples of this?  I'd love to see when I'm doing things just for the sake of "it's right because it's a design pattern."  I get caught up in this type of thing, thinking I'm doing it wrong because a book said so.

Comment: For anyone who considers to reference this answer, please take into account that "PHP sites seem to run faster" is anecdotal evidence and can not be used to proof anything if you expect any credibility.

Answer (score 28):

## Speed doesn't matter

in most cases.

Processing is cheap. Code in what you're comfortable with. Writing proper code goes much further for speed then choosing a language. Solid coding conventions and design plan will also help more.

Comment: Furthermore, it'd be easy to write fast or slow applications in either language by choosing good or poor datastructures and algorithms.

Comment: @sarnold: Correct. Another thing to consider (though technically outside the scope) is development time. If you're not a Java developer you aren't going to like the J2EE development cycle of repackage, redeploy, test.

Comment: Can you generate actual web pages with java? Because otherwise applet/VM initialisation time kills any site for me.

Comment: To me, answers like this are as vague and unhelpful as questions like these.  In some situations, speed really does matter.  Inside loops, batch processing, etc.  We have no idea what the original poster wanted, so why not trust that it really was something for which speed mattered?  The reality of the situation is that we have no idea what the context of this question is: what this person is trying to achieve - it's far too vague - and it's for that reason I nominated closing it.

Comment: @Graphain, see  Java EE - servlet API.

Comment: Speed matters a great deal for some applications.  Obviously solid code and design are important, but speed can make huge differences in an application's usability and overall success.

Comment: @DanielPereira Depends on what you're doing of course.

Comment: I disagree. Slow sites are boring. If it takes 5 second to provide a response on an unloaded machine, adding more resources is useless. And still if ram and cpu are relatively cheap, they cost energy and system administrators salaries to be used.

Comment: @Paolo I'm pointing out you can always add more processing power to run it and shipping faster is better than refining performance, until you need to refine performance that is. You won't know what you'll need to refine performance wise until you ship something.

Comment: SPEED DOES MATTER. Why does a person take a jet over a car from Los Angeles to Chicago?, because it's 10x faster!  Over the many years I've been writing backend web logic I often run across the ignorant who says speed isn't important, doesn't matter, can't accurately test performance, etc and so on and on (f# lame).  SPEED DOES MATTER. Java outperforms PHP in every category (raw servlets). Speed matters BECAUSE it's how efficiently your CPUS and IO are being utilized, speed means more users per server, which means less $$$$ in server costs. SPEED MATTERS VERY MUCH INDEED. Write in Java.

Comment: Mostly for websites speed does not matter. Because the resources of the servers is way to high to make any impact. But there are cases where speed does matter, as stated in other comments. But then I would argue that neither Java or PHP (or any high level language) is a good choice. But to give a clear answer it is required to have more information. For data science I would choose R or C/C++ for more memory optimised code.

Comment: I actually think PHP on its own is quite fast.  Perhaps not as fast as Java, but I once had an installation of PHP+Nginx running on a heavily loaded server that could deal with 5000 multiple requests per second.   The things that DO and almost usually cause bottlenecks and slowdowns are inefficient code or slow storage engines, i.e MySQLs.  So the issue realy isn't PHP or Java, its whether your code is efficient or not.  With an inefficient code, even a C++ program will run slower than an optimized PHP one.

Answer (score 12):

Best answer I could find

"stuff to consider:

1. Java web applications are compiled
   to bytecode. Even JSPs, which are
   compiled at runtime. This is an
   advantage over most uses of PHP,
   where the Zend Optimizer is not in
   use.
2. Data can be cached in a live servlet
   instance - no direct/easy way of
   doing this in PHP to my knowledge
   (there is only ever a single
   instance of a servlet/JSP in memory)

   - If anybody knows how to cache data in PHP without resorting to ugly
     hacks, please enlighten me!
3. Java applications tend to be
   n-tiered, which generally results in
   a more maintainable application at a
   slight performance penalty. This
   probably sounds trollish, but
   honestly: even within Java itself
   direct use of JDBC will always be
   faster than going through three
   layers of objects to the database.

But is an n-tiered Java application able to hit the database sooner than an uncompiled, hacked-up monolithic PHP script? I don't think there's an answer to that question.

All that said, I'm working on an n-tiered MVC framework for php 5 (it's called Pure (http://www.sf.net/projects/php-pure)), so my PHP applications are generally n-tiered too. I'll worry about speed when and if it becomes an issue. For now, it's definitely not an issue."

[courtesy of krumms](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-373862.html)

Comment: PHP cache: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php also to share a cache among more than one server Memcache: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Comment: Since PHP 5.5 the [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) replaced the old APC.

Comment: Your statement about monolithic php is quite minimizing what php can actually do. My php application is using classes and is designed in a n-tier layers as well.

Answer (score 7):

Speed aside, I believe the performance of Java is better than PHP. But developing a project in PHP is faster.

Comment: If you're a shop full of Java developers, it's faster to develop a project in Java.  How fast it is to develop in just depends on what your specialty, I'd say.

Comment: and what if you don't java neither php?

Comment: Development in PHP IS NOT FASTER than Java. I code in both. Of course it depends on complexity, but they're both about the same in coding in nearly every scenario.

Comment: One thing is pain in java that for simple work you have to include lots of classes and interfaces
like handling a simple form in php is easier than in jsp/jsf etc because it requires interfaces and classes while in php its simple as cout in c++ :)

Comment: I came from years of using PHP at my job to a new position using Java. I'd say both have their strengths. I'm here reading this question because I'm starting a new side-project and trying to pick between the two and I am having a hard time doing so. Also, I'm considering node, which is a dark horse candidate.

Answer (score 4):

Can't answer this question with one or the other unless you define what you want to measure the speed *of*.

Some things are much faster in PHP (in a native function for example), other things are much faster in Java.

Comment: Fact: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=java&lang2=php&data=u64q

Comment: And "other things are much faster than Java" for isn't accurate at all. Java blows pretty much everything away, runs equally as fast as C++ under most load. The only things reasonably faster would be C and Assembly language. Raw Java servlets (without the MVC baggage) are screaming fast. I speak over 10 computer languages fluently for 35 years. I've done all the testing, all the performance tests. Java dominates and it's the most misunderstood language, ironically its also the best to code in for many reasons.

Comment: PHP native functions and extensions are overwhelmingly written in C, in many cases they just hook straight into C standard library functions.  Any time you're doing heavy text or image processing for example, doing it via built-in functions like Perl regular expressions, text searching and manipulation, GD/imagemagick, XML processing etc will be lightning fast in PHP because the part of your code that does the heavy lifting will all be in a C function.  To take a contrived but practical example, Perl regular expressions will be many times faster in PHP than Java, because in PHP it's native.

Comment: When benchmarking a language you typically don't test the performance of library functions, you test primitives implemented in the language you're testing.  Java will far outshine PHP in that regard (notwithstanding stuff like HHVM).

Answer (score 3):

The intent of each language is substantially different from the other, so if you're debating over which to use for a particular task, you should generally based the decision on that task (and how well suited each language is to it) rather than performance.

For raw performance of code written in the language (as opposed to simply calling code in the standard library), Java will probably run faster than PHP as an extremely general rule. If that matters, chances are that PHP just isn't very well suited to the task at hand.

Comment: I disagree. Base EVERYTHING on performance. Java is super performant, PHP simply isn't.  If you don't know Java, learn it -- it's f# easy, compiled and fast.  Raw Java Servlet programming isn't that much unlike PHP "object oriented" programming (yes, quotes), except with Java you get strict language consistency, PHP is a slow, hack job of a language.  You also WANT the strict typing Java offers, you don't know it yet, but you do.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell: Thanks for the input, but you might want to look at my profile. While I'd agree that PHP is generally slower than Java, it's purely a matter of degree--at least to me, neither qualifies as anywhere close to "fast" (but if you look at my profile, you'll realize I mostly write C++, and assembly language when speed really matters). If you're basing (even close to) everything on performance, 1) you're probably making a mistake, and 2) you shouldn't be using either PHP *or* Java.

Comment: For WEB (that's the question). While you may enjoy developing web sites in assembly language (or C++), I don't (/s). So, then what are the options? Many of course, but when it comes to performance for web apps, Java is absolutely the way to go, hands down, without exception. You should ABSOLUTELY base your work around performance and optimization, time IS money, if your CPU's are working with a lesser JITc or Bytecode you are wasting energy and resources. Pure Java servlets (without the MVC baggage) are highly performant, equal to C++ in performance. You're misinformed.

Comment: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=java&lang2=gpp&data=u64q